# Access Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 REST WEB API

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, dynamics-crm, adfs

I need to access CRM odata REST API for Integration. I have a php cron job for syncing data from CRM. When I hit the endpoint of CRM WEB API https://internal.crm.org.com:5443/appname/api/data/v8.0/  from browser I redirect to the following link :
https://adfs.crm.org.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https://internal.crm.org.com:5443/&wctx=rm=1&id=4d65271b-682e-44bb-80ce-ed44b5370ed7&ru=%2forgTechnicalTraining%2fdefault.aspx&wct=2016-11-02T07:15:47Z&wauth=urn:federation:authentication:windows
and a window is shown to authenticate using username, and password.

So my question is how to authenticate with the resources server?
Microsoft point me to this page 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt622431.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1
and this guy explain how to authenticate using oauth2 
http://www.powerobjects.com/2016/01/22/start-your-engines-getting-started-with-the-crm-2016-web-api/#collapse2

Microsoft said dynamics 365 is using three different security models (claims, active dirctory, and auth2 authentications)

Comment: Your link seems to be incorrect. Please fix that!

Comment: I know it's incorrect just example with that format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully integrated with CRM web api 2016 using the ws-trust protocol.

[This lib](https://github.com/zandbelt/php-ws-trust-client) are do the heavy work for you and implment the ws-trust protocol messages.
Steps To authenticate with CRM that is protoected by ADFS 3.0 
1- Get the samel security token (the endpoint for ws-trust for active authenticate need to be configured on adfs server)
2- Include that token per http request within the header as earer token
Code:

```
<?php

include_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/http.php';
include_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/wstrust.php';

// username/password of a user in the LDAP directory
// LDAP as configured in the PingFederate Username Token WS-Trust connection settings for Salesforce
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

// RST appliesTo
$appliesTo = 'crmservice/api/data/v8.0/';

//STS service
$IPSTS = 'org/adfs/services/trust/13/UsernameMixed';

// special token type (needs to be enabled in run.properties)
$tokenType = WSTRUST::TOKENTYPE_SAML20;

// call to IP-STS, authenticate with uname/pwd, retrieve RSTR with generated token
//get security token
$result = HTTP::doSOAP(
        $IPSTS,
        WSTRUST::getRSTHeader(
                WSTRUST::getUserNameToken($username, $password),
                WSTRUST::getTimestampHeader(), $IPSTS),
        WSTRUST::getRST($tokenType, $appliesTo)
);

// parse the RSTR that is returned
list($dom, $xpath, $token, $proofKey) = WSTRUST::parseRSTR($result);

$xpath->registerNamespace('saml', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion');
$token =  $xpath->query('saml:EncryptedAssertion', $token);
$token = $token->item(0);

// now pass the encrypted assertion to the RP
$ts = WSTRUST::getTimestampHeader('_0');
$token = $dom->saveXML($token);

//include the token with the http header per request  like this Authorization: Bearer $token
```